# KML file not formatting a drawn line

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am using the following code to generate a line in Google Earth, however the formatting of the line is not changing.

```
<Placemark>
<LineString>
<Style id="bendigo_line">
    <LineStyle>
        <width>3</width>
        <color>64F0FF14</color>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<coordinates>
-15,52,0
-20,53,0
-30,53,0
-40,53,0
-50,52,0
-53.233333,51.166667


</coordinates>
</LineString>
</Placemark>
```

I'm unsure of what I am doing wrong as this method has worked in the past and now doesn't change the line from the default thickness and colour.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Style>` element must appear outside the `<LineString>` element. KML requires elements in a particular order.

For the syntax of the Placemark refer to the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#placemark).

Try changing your KML to this order of elements:

```
<Placemark>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
        <width>3</width>
        <color>64F0FF14</color>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <LineString>
    <coordinates>
     ...
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

When there are problems with KML try first to validate it using the [KML Validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/validate.htm).